# python3 print landscape image/file with specified printer

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, printing, pywin32

I want to print a pdf file (or image) that I create on my script with a specified printer but the file is landscape orientation. I have tried the [Tim Golden's python print](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) but it is printed wrong and most of the image is not printed or I get an error message that the specified file is not found. This is the error: **"pywintypes.error: (2, 'ShellExecute', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')"**
and the command is this: ***win32api.ShellExecute (0, "print", filename, '/d:"%s"' % printer_name, ".", 0)***. Of course *filename* and *printer* are strings and printer name is taken from win32print.EnumPrinters(2,None,1)

Here is my printing function:

```
def programA_printer():
    global name
    global printer_name
    global event2
    # time.sleep(3)
    i=0
    while True:
        if not event2.is_set():
            try:
                img = Image.open("Program_A_graph.png", 'r')
                if (time.time()-(os.path.getmtime("Program_A_graph.png")) < 1.75):
                    break
            except OSError as identifier:
                i = i+1
                print(identifier)
                time.sleep(1)
                if i>5:
                    print("Υπήρξε πρόβλημα, δεν εκτυπώνω και συνεχίζω στο επόμενο σετ!")
                    return


    serial_number_message = int(time.time())

    # img.show(title="Final Result")
    img.convert('RGB').save('./εκτυπώσεις/'+str(serial_number_message)+'.pdf', format="PDF", resolution=100.0)

#win32api.ShellExecute (0, "print", './εκτυπώσεις/'+str(serial_number_message)+'.pdf', '/d:"%s"' % printer_name, ".",0)
#win32api.ShellExecute (0, "print", './εκτυπώσεις/'+str(serial_number_message)+'.pdf', '/d:"%s"' % printer_name, "./εκτυπώσεις",0)
    HORZRES = 10
    VERTRES = 10

    PHYSICALWIDTH = 110
    PHYSICALHEIGHT = 111

    PHYSICALOFFSETX = 112
    PHYSICALOFFSETY = 113

    hDC = win32ui.CreateDC()
    hDC.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
    printable_area = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES), hDC.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES)
    printer_size = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALWIDTH), hDC.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALHEIGHT)
    printer_margins = hDC.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALOFFSETX), hDC.GetDeviceCaps(PHYSICALOFFSETY)

    bmp = img
    if bmp.size[0] > bmp.size[1]:
        bmp = bmp.rotate(90)

    ratios = [1.0 * printable_area[0] / bmp.size[0], 1.0 * printable_area[1] / bmp.size[1]]
    scale = min(ratios)

    hDC.StartDoc("Result")
    hDC.StartPage()

    dib = ImageWin.Dib(bmp)
    scaled_width, scaled_height = [int(scale * i) for i in bmp.size]
    x1 = int((printer_size[0] - scaled_width) / 2)
    y1 = int((printer_size[1] - scaled_height) / 2)
    x2 = x1 + scaled_width
    y2 = y1 + scaled_height
    dib.draw(hDC.GetHandleOutput(), (x1, y1, x2, y2))

    hDC.EndPage()
    hDC.EndDoc()
    hDC.DeleteDC()
```

I don't know what else to try. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please post the code that is giving rise to this error, and the full stack trace of the error.  The reference you give offers half a dozen different approaches. You are asking us to guess which you have chosen, imagine your code, and then suggest what might be wrong inside it.

Comment: @BoarGules I added the code, the commented lines using win32api.ShellExecute are the other ways I tries to print the pdf file I create instead of the image from PIL.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> bmp = bmp.rotate(90)
> ```

This will crop the image. Use `img.rotate(90, expand=True)` to flip the image properly.

You can use `SetViewportExt`/`SetWindowExt` instead of manually calculating the bitmap ratio to printer resolution. You also need to account for printer's margin. See example below.

The system error for file not found error is separate. Use the debugger to find where it occurs.

```
import win32ui, win32con
from PIL import Image, ImageWin

def print_test(printer_name):

    try:
        filename = "Program_A_graph.png"
        img = Image.open(filename, 'r')
    except:
        print("error")
        return

    hdc = win32ui.CreateDC()
    hdc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)

    horzres = hdc.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.HORZRES)
    vertres = hdc.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.VERTRES)

    landscape = horzres > vertres

    if landscape:
        if img.size[1] > img.size[0]:
            print('Landscape mode, tall image, rotate bitmap.')
            img = img.rotate(90, expand=True)
    else:
        if img.size[1] < img.size[0]:
            print('Portrait mode, wide image, rotate bitmap.')
            img = img.rotate(90, expand=True)

    img_width = img.size[0]
    img_height = img.size[1]

    if landscape:
        #we want image width to match page width
        ratio = vertres / horzres
        max_width = img_width
        max_height = (int)(img_width * ratio)
    else:
        #we want image height to match page height
        ratio = horzres / vertres
        max_height = img_height
        max_width = (int)(max_height * ratio)

    #map image size to page size
    hdc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_ISOTROPIC)
    hdc.SetViewportExt((horzres, vertres));
    hdc.SetWindowExt((max_width, max_height))

    #offset image so it is centered horizontally
    offset_x = (int)((max_width - img_width)/2)
    offset_y = (int)((max_height - img_height)/2)
    hdc.SetWindowOrg((-offset_x, -offset_y)) 

    hdc.StartDoc('Result')
    hdc.StartPage()

    dib = ImageWin.Dib(img)
    dib.draw(hdc.GetHandleOutput(), (0, 0, img_width, img_height))

    hdc.EndPage()
    hdc.EndDoc()
    hdc.DeleteDC()

    print( 'Debug info:' )
    print( 'Landscape: %d' % landscape )
    print( 'horzres: %d' % horzres )
    print( 'vertres: %d' % vertres )

    print( 'img_width: %d' % img_width )
    print( 'img_height: %d' % img_height )

    print( 'max_width: %d' % max_width )
    print( 'max_height: %d' % max_height )

    print( 'offset_x: %d' % offset_x )
    print( 'offset_y: %d' % offset_y )
```

Comment: This is very nice, I can see you know so much more about it, but now the image if printed pushed out of the paper on the top left corner. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please see edit. I forgot the margin. This should stretch/center to the max printable area.

Comment: I tried this and it stretches the image more than the papersize (A4), so now the left and right sides are off the paper. What can I do? Also, I made a mistake, the image is in the right orientation (landscape) so no rotation is needed. Just to make the image fit the papersize and not change the aspect ratio. Sorry for the mix up.

Comment: Please try the 3rd update I made. It also prints "Debug info". Edit the question and show the result for those values. At least show the size of bitmap. Printer paper size shouldn't matter with this code.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmak Shemirani above deserves full credit for most of the code below. I simply added a section which allows you to choose the page size and/or force the orientation. You can also use the devmode in the win32con easily now to push the image around as needed.

```
def print_test(filename, page_size="11x17", page_orientation="landscape", printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()):

    try:
        img = Image.open(filename, 'r')
    except:
        print("error")
        return

    # open the printer.
    hprinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

    # retrieve default settings.  this code does not work on
    devmode = win32print.GetPrinter(hprinter, 2)["pDevMode"]

    # change paper size and orientation
    # all numbers can be found here -
    # https://github.com/SublimeText/Pywin32/blob/master/lib/x64/win32/lib/win32con.py
    if page_size == "letter":
        devmode.PaperSize = 1 # 11x17 = 17, letter = 1
    elif page_size == "11x17":
        devmode.PaperSize = 17 # 11x17 = 17, letter = 1

    # 1 = portrait, 2 = landscape
    if page_orientation == "portait":
        devmode.Orientation = 2
    elif page_orientation == "landscape":
        devmode.Orientation = 2

    # create dc using new settings
    # first get the integer hDC value - note that we need the name
    hdc = win32gui.CreateDC("WINSPOOL", printer_name, devmode)
    # next create a PyCDC from the hDC.
    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hdc)


    horzres = hdc.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.HORZRES)
    vertres = hdc.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.VERTRES)

    landscape = horzres > vertres

    if landscape:
        if img.size[1] > img.size[0]:
            print('Landscape mode, tall image, rotate bitmap.')
            img = img.rotate(90, expand=True)
    else:
        if img.size[1] < img.size[0]:
            print('Portrait mode, wide image, rotate bitmap.')
            img = img.rotate(90, expand=True)

    img_width = img.size[0]
    img_height = img.size[1]

    if landscape:
        #we want image width to match page width
        ratio = vertres / horzres
        max_width = img_width
        max_height = (int)(img_width * ratio)
    else:
        #we want image height to match page height
        ratio = horzres / vertres
        max_height = img_height
        max_width = (int)(max_height * ratio)

    #map image size to page size
    hdc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_ISOTROPIC)
    hdc.SetViewportExt((horzres, vertres));
    hdc.SetWindowExt((max_width, max_height))

    #offset image so it is centered horizontally
    offset_x = (int)((max_width - img_width)/2)
    offset_y = (int)((max_height - img_height)/2)
    hdc.SetWindowOrg((-offset_x, -offset_y)) 

    hdc.StartDoc('Result')
    hdc.StartPage()

    dib = ImageWin.Dib(img)
    dib.draw(hdc.GetHandleOutput(), (0, 0, img_width, img_height))

    hdc.EndPage()
    hdc.EndDoc()
    hdc.DeleteDC()
```